# Deleting from a List

Tags: java, swing, jlist

In this code, when I select an element from the middle of the list and delete, the elements below the selected element are also removed from "view". But they are present in the database and appear once again when the app is run. Please help me with this mistake. Thanks.

```
DeleteController delController = new DeleteController();
delController.deleteInfo(dbId);
this.jList1 = list;
AbstractListModel model = (AbstractListModel) jList1.getModel();
int numberElements = model.getSize();
final String[] allElements = new String[numberElements + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < numberElements - 1; i++) {
    String val = (String) model.getElementAt(i);
    if (!dbId.equals(val)) {
        allElements[i] = (String) model.getElementAt(i);
    }
}
jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {

    String[] strings = allElements;

    public int getSize() {
        return strings.length;
    }

    public Object getElementAt(int i) {
        return strings[i];
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you show the code that actually performs the delete. Better: post a SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DefaultListModel`. It has `removeElementAt()` method

Comment: +1, also, you can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). It has a working example of how to dynamically add/remove items from a DefaultListModel.